# How to compare instances of Type for equality

Tags: java, reflection

Given two instances of [Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html):

```
Type type1;
Type type2;
```

How to can I check if they are `equal`?

I'm calling `toString` and comparing their values, as such:

```
if (type1.toString().equals(type2.toString())) {
    ....
}
```

I tested it with multiple and nested parameterized types and so far it seems to be consistent. But I would like to know if there is a formal way to do it.

Comment: Why not use equals(), as for any other object?

Comment: `Type` does not define rules for `equals`. Unless you know the underlying implementation, don't depend on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `Type` instances generated by the Java runtime have correct equals() and hashCode() implementations, so you can and should just use equals() to compare them.

For example, the Javadoc for `ParameterizedType` contains this:

> Instances of classes that implement this interface must implement an equals() method that equates any two instances that share the same generic type declaration and have equal type parameters.

`Class` objects inherit their equals() and hashCode() implementations from `Object`, but that's correct because `Class` objects have reference equality.

Normal equals() should also be substantially faster and more memory efficient than converting types to strings.

Comment: I also stumbled over this when I tried to create my own `ParameterizedType` implementation. The problem is: You don't know how to implement `hashCode`! But that's a more general problem, I guess.

Comment: I've run all my tests using equals and they pass, as same as using toString. So I guess this is the right answer.

Comment: Is this guaranteed somewhere?  In the javadoc, I see such a guarantee for ParameterizedType and TypeVariable, but not GenericArrayType and WildcardType.

Comment: The Guava library definitely depends on this behavior for a bunch of stuff under `com.google.common.reflect` which is used pretty widely. This is semi-undocumented (and [broke at least once before](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1635), but not in a way that's relevant to this question) but is generally stable enough for large production codebases to depend on. I would consider it on par with `sun.misc.Unsafe` as being a de facto API these days.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the `toString()` method is explicitly defined in whatever class you're creating for `Type`, you'll be getting false every time *except* if they are the same object. This is also true if you're just trying to use `a.equals(b)` for `Type a; Type b;`: `equals()` only compares the address values of both objects. If you want to check if two differently allocated objects contain the same corresponding member variables, you'll have to define the `equals()` method in that class.

Comment: Identity semantics are actually correct for most Type instances, e.g. Class. The exceptions like ParameterizedType and TypeWildcard require correct equals implementations. And unless you're doing something really weird, nobody writes their own implementations of Type.